# randomness of encrypt

Tags: encryption, randomness

In the paper "[Efficient Encryption from Random Quasi-Cyclic Codes](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/1194.pdf)" of Gaborit et al. p.14, I read "Encrypt$(pk=(G,Q,s),\mu,\theta)$: uses randomness $\theta$ to generate $\epsilon \xleftarrow{\\\$}V,r=(r_1,r_2) \xleftarrow{\\\$}V^2$...". Does it mean exactly "uses randomness $\theta$"? Where Can I find a descryption of a PKE in this terms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an encryption scheme to satisfy the standard notion of security ([IND-CPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability)), its encryption algorithm *must* be [randomised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_algorithm). Therefore $\textsf{Encrypt}$ has access to random coins, denoted here by $\theta$. It is usually implicit in the syntax of $\textsf{Encrypt}$
$$c\leftarrow\textsf{Encrypt}(pk,m),$$ but it can be made explicit as
$$c=\textsf{Encrypt}(pk,m;\theta).$$

For example, the encryption algorithm in [El Gamal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption) (which is IND-CPA secure under the [DDH assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decisional_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_assumption)) with public key $pk=(G,g,h,q)$ and message $m\in G$ can be described as
$$(c_1=g^r,c_2=h^r\cdot m)=\mathsf{Encrypt}(pk,m;\theta),$$
where the random coin $\theta$ (interpreted as a string) is used to sample $r\in[1,q-1]$.